# Twilio call: Play two audio files

Tags: twilio

Using  Twilio API I managed to make a call and play one audio file, but I did not succeed to play two files. how can I do it?

Here is my code:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Call(string callToNumber, string audioUrl)
        {
            // Set our Account SID and AuthToken
            var accountSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ACCOUNT_SID"];
            var authToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AUTH_TOKEN"];
            var twilioNumber = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioMobileNumber"];


            // Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
            var client = new TwilioRestClient(accountSid, authToken);

            // Initiate a new outbound call
            var call = client.InitiateOutboundCall
                (
                    twilioNumber,  
                    callToNumber,
                    audioUrl   
                   // ,audioUrl2 -- I want to add another file              
                 );

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Twilio evangelist here.

Is the `audiofile` variable just a URL to a wav or mp3?  If it is, then you'll need to change that to a URL that can return some TwiML that includes two [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) verbs, like this:

```
<Response>
    <Play>http://example.com/music1.mp3</Play>
    <Play>http://example.com/music2.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: What about client.InitiateOutboundCall() can I use two audio URLs with it?

Comment: No.  You can only pass a single URL to the method, but as I said that URL can return TwiML like I showed above that has multiple audio URLs.  If you just need some static TwiML, I'd suggest looking at http://twimlbin.com